# Standby/Offline stream image with ffmpeg/nginx RTMP

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, nginx, rtmp

Is there a way to script NGINX RTMP to show a Offline/Standby video or static image when there is no incoming streams to rebroadcast?

The idea is that when there is no incoming RTMP streams (ffmpeg, open broadcast software, other streaming software) actively streaming content I would want NGINX to show a standby/offline video or image to the views who are connected. And then when a user does start streaming NGINX will remove the standby video/image and start rebroadcasting the streamed media to the connected clients.

Does the RTMP module have this support built in? If not is it possible to some how use the events system to start/stop a local ffmpeg instance to stream the standby and to kill it when a real stream starts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `<head>` section of where you are hosting your player:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.clappr.io/latest/clappr.min.js"></script>
```

Then put this in your `<body>`

```
<div id="player" style="float: left; width: 75%; height: 85vh;">
<script>

var targetPlayerElement = "#player"; //player element that it spawns on
var offlineImage = "INSERT IMG URL HERE"; //offline image
var streamURL = "http://YOUR IP HERE/live/";
checkLive();
var isLive = false;
function checkLive() {
    var player;
    console.log("Checking stream status...");
    $.ajax({

      url: streamURL, //stream url
      success: function(data){
        if(!isLive)
        {
            $(targetPlayerElement).empty();
            isLive = true;
            player = new Clappr.Player({source: streamURL, parentId: targetPlayerElement, autoPlay: "true", width: "100%", height: "100%", maxBufferLength: 3, mediacontrol: {seekbar: "#7a17ff", buttons: "#ff1a68"}, actualLiveTime: true, playbackNotSupportedMessage: 'Please try on a different browser', useHardwareVideoDecoder: false,});
            console.log("Stream is running; creating player");

        }
      },
      error: function(data){
        if(isLive)
        {
            isLive = false;
            $(targetPlayerElement).empty();
            $(targetPlayerElement).html("<img src='"+ offlineImage + "'alt='offline' width='100%' height='100%'/>");
        }
        if(!isLive)
            $(targetPlayerElement).html("<img src='"+ offlineImage + "'alt='offline' width='100%' height='100%'/>");
      },
    })
    setTimeout(checkLive, 5000);
}
</script>
</div>
```

This is my personal script for my stream a friend made for me. This uses the Clappr player and will automatically switch between the image you enter and the start of the stream and vice versa. Enjoy.